# Even when data not saved in DB, binding is updated

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a database with servers (dummy data for now) with IP-addresses to ping. After a successful ping, the server status is set to online.

I ran the application and the changes were shown in both the application and the database. So I thought all was fine.

Until I commented out the saving to the database part. And indeed, the changes do not save to the database. However, the changes do show so my binding does get updated.

I want the data shown in the application to match the database. So when the saving to DB fails, the application data does not change and the application and DB still match.

Here's the code, I hope you can help me out :)

```
// Get all servers that have an IP adress.
var query =
   from server in dataEntities.Server
   where server.IPAdress != null
   select server;

// Ping the servers from the query.
foreach (Server server in query)
{
    IPAdress = server.IPAdress;
    Boolean online = checkPing.sendPing(IPAdress);
    // Change the status according to the ping result.
    if (online == true)
        server.Status = true;
    else if (online == false)
        server.Status = false;
}

// Save the changes in status in the DB.
/*try
{
    dataEntities.SaveChanges();
}
catch (Exception oops)
{
    Console.WriteLine(oops);
    // Provide for exceptions.
}*/
```

Comment: How do you expect WPF to know what is on the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `SaveChanges` fails, then you will need to rollback your entity's values back to what they originally were.

In your `DbContext` class, you can add a method called `Rollback`, it'll look something like this:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    //DataSets and what not.
    //...

    public void Rollback()
    {
        //Get all entities
        var entries = this.ChangeTracker.Entries().ToList();

        var changed = entries.Where(x => x.State != EntityState.Unchanged).ToList();
        var modified = changed.Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();
        var added = changed.Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added).ToList();
        var deleted = changed.Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Deleted).ToList();

        //Reset values for modified entries
        foreach (var entry in modified)
        {
            entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entry.OriginalValues);
            entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        }

        //Remove any added entries
        foreach (var entry in added)
            entry.State = EntityState.Detached;

        //Undo any deleted entries
        foreach (var entry in deleted)
            entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    }
}
```

You can simply call this method in your `catch`:

```
try
{
    dataEntities.SaveChanges();
}
catch (Exception oops)
{
    //Rollback all changes
    dataEntities.Rollback();
}
```

Note that `INotifyPropertyChanged` will need to be implemented on properties that are bound to the view, this will ensure that any changes that the rollback performs will be pushed back to the view.